# regex case insensitive filtering of columns in pandas

Tags: csv, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to match a string(column) in csv files in python using Python but it does not match anything. I want the string to be match to be case insensitive. I am quite new but this is what I tried to do

```
test = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
mytest= pd.DataFrame(test, columns=[re.search("[a-zA-Z1-9_]", "columnname1", re.IGNORECASE),])
print(mytest)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand what you're after you can `filter` your df to only return the columns where the name matches and make it case-insensitive:

```
In [298]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'columnname1':np.arange(5), 'ColumnName1':np.arange(5), 'columnname2':0, 'column name 1':0})
df
Out[298]:
   ColumnName1  column name 1  columnname1  columnname2
0            0              0            0            0
1            1              0            1            0
2            2              0            2            0
3            3              0            3            0
4            4              0            4            0

In [299]:

import re
df.filter(regex=re.compile("columnname1", re.IGNORECASE))
Out[299]:
   ColumnName1  columnname1
0            0            0
1            1            1
2            2            2
3            3            3
4            4            4
```

**EDIT**

For matching just the name without words preceding it, so matching on 'Test' but not 'My Test':

```
In [52]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Test':np.arange(5), 'ColumnName1':np.arange(5), 'My Test':0, 'My column name 1':0})
import re
df.filter(regex=re.compile(r"^Test$", re.IGNORECASE))
Out[52]:
   Test
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
```

So the `^` looks for 'Test' at the beginning of the str and the `$` marks the end of the pattern to search, there is a handy [cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx).

Comment: thank you, but i really want is that assuming that i have all those columns you put in the  example above in a csv file and i want to retrieve just one of them (case insensitive). what should i do? if case sensitive, i can easily do that with mytest=pd.DataFrame(test, columns=["Columnname1"]  but what if i write instead  columns=["COLUMnNaMe1"]? what should i do in that case? because that is what i want actually to do. Thank you

Comment: Are you worried about loading the entire csv and then filtering afterwards? You can just get the column list first by reading a single line from the csv and then filter this and pass as a param. So `cols=pd.read_csv(file_path, nrows=1)` then parse the cols as my code snippet above, then use this to load just those columns: `df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=filtered_cols)`

Comment: what i am worried about is that if what i want to retrieve in a file is not well written for example COLUMNName1 instead of Columnname1, if i want to print, i get NaN though Columnname1 is in the file; so it is case sensitive

Comment: I don't understand your concern, once you find the case insensitive matches like I've shown you then have a list of matching columns, it'll then just work. If your column names are unique you could just pre-process them and write the column names out all lowercase and then this becomes a non-issue

Comment: @ EdChum your answer is fine thank you;  but what you propose will   print ColumnName1  column name 1  columnname1  .  My concern is, is i want to retrieve  ColumnName1, but i pass COLUMNname1, i want to be able to retrieve ColumnName1; when i use your example in my case, it retrieve any column that has COLUMNname1 as a substring

Comment: No it doesn't have read the output, it's matching on the lowercased string of the pattern, there is no match against the column names with white spaces

Comment: @EdChumi have:  test=pd.read_csv(filename.csv)  then i use  mytest=re.filter(regex="ColumnNaMe1", re.INGNORECASE)  print(mytest) and it prints as well white space; anyway i will try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @EdChumi, i have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code; but undortunatly it is still the same. Mine code using the solution you put, match as well column name with the with space. Did yours not match the white space: could pls try with something like column name1= test; column  name2= my test where the value i put is TEst. could you please try that using your solution and show tell me what is the results; and if it does the correct marching, could you please show me the snippet. Sorry for those questions; i am very new to programming and to python. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to match exactly? my code matches just as a case insensitive pattern, if you're trying to match on a space then you need to give examples

Comment: I am trying to find a column with a column name in my csv file name Test, However, in my file, i also have a column with a  name my Test. I want to match Test only in my file and not my Test as well.

Comment: Could you try this: `import re
df.filter(regex=re.compile(r"^Test$", re.IGNORECASE))`